# Get the value from jQuery-ui slider

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have used the slider from the jQuery UI. I created the sliders and it works fine.

Now I need to take the value of the slider and assign it to a variable, so that I can save it in the database.

Can you please explain me how to do this?

How can I use this variable to save it to the database ( I use PHP ).

Comment: Show some tries, some code please.

Comment: Is the problem getting the value or how to save it to a database?

Comment: @Juhana to save it to the database...

Comment: The question reads now as if the problem is getting the value in the first place (that's why it's closed as a duplicate of an unrelated question). You might want to edit the question to clarify it so that it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of slider, you can do:

```
var val = $("#sliderID").slider("value");
```

Check [documnetation](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#slider").slider({
  value: 100,
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  step: 50,
  slide: function (event, ui) {
    $("#amount").val("$" + ui.value);
  }
});
$("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider").slider("value"));
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2XNjq/)